# Unable to create react project - operation not permitted

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a react project using following command.

```
npx create-react-app mywebsite
```

but getting this error.

> command not found: create-react-app

I have tried with sudo command but getting same issue.

Comment: Did you have  NodeJS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

and then do `npx create-react-app mywebsite`

Comment: also please check if you have nodejs installed on your system globally

Comment: to do that you can do something like this  node --version. if you find something like this v10.19.0 then it is fine otherwise install it